# Catch call to Web API 2 before it reach method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I am having problem with a call to:

```
[HttpDelete]
public IHttpActionResult DeleteFile(Guid appendixId, Guid? storageId)
```

The routing seems okey but get get "405 Method Not Allowed".

I am wondering if there is a way to hock in to web api to catch the call as early as possible. That way I can know what might be wrong. Anyone know a way?

The problem seems not to be in the code. Is seems to be somewhere else. The reason for this is that I shelved and a colleague ran the exact same code and it worked. What on my machine could give this kind of error?

Comment: How do you apply the request ?

Comment: How do you make the call? You can get this error if you use the *wrong* route. Did you use `myController/deletefile?appendixId=aaa&storageId=bbb` ? Something else?

Comment: The problem was not the route it was on my computer. It was WebDav that blocked my calls.

Answer (score 0):

if you trying on iis express

open

%userprofile%\documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config

and add DELETE verb to ExtensionlessUrl tag.

Comment: You are *assuming* this isn't a bad route. Making server-wide changes "just in case" can lead to some very nasty problems

Comment: I am not running express

Comment: what is iis version ?